# C# Listbox display duplicate ble device

Tags: c#

When I run the code and I press the 'search' button, it can detect nearby ble device. However, it displays many of the same name. how do I fix this?

```
  public Form1()
    {
      items = new List<string>();
      InitializeComponent();
      txtStatus.Text = "Press 'Search' to begin";
      var watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
      watcher.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;

      watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;
      watcher.Start();
    }

    private void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
      items.Add(eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Yann. Please check in with the [how to ask a good question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you're unsure of how to go about formatting your questions for us.

Comment: `items` is of type `list`, if you want to add **distinct** values then use `HashSet` instead of `List`

Answer (score 0):

In your `OnAdvertisementReceived` function, you aren't checking if the item already exists within your list before pushing it back.

Try something like the following:

```
private void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    //If the list does not already have this name inside of it
    if(items.Contains(eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName) == false)
    {
        //Add it into the list, because it must be new! (>*3*)>
        items.Add(eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName);
    }
}
```